# Shapes are automatically changing their names

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, shapes

I have used "Record Macro" to find Shape names in VBA

First, it showed the name of a shape as "**Snip Diagonal Corner Rectangle 11**".
But, after some days, I cannot run a macro related to this shape, and it notified me that "**The item with the specific name wasn't found**".
When I rechecked it name by "Record Macro" again, the name was changed to "**Rectangle: Diagonal Corners Snipped 11**".

I am quite confused with the "Record Macro" function that whether it has different way of calling shape names each time or this is somehow the result of any mistake caused by operators.

If any one get any idea about this, please explain to me. Thank you!

Comment: It would be best to post your code. But I doubt that you will get an answer because there is no way to recreate the issue.  Good Luck!

Comment: Why does the name matter?  You should either be setting it to an Object variable or using it's `AutoShapeType` property `msoShapeSnip2DiagRectangle` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating it a few different ways, and like @TinMan said, I can't reproduce it.
To my point, why does it matter?  If you need to manipulate it, store it as variable, or go search for it later by looking for it's `AutoShapeType` property

```
Dim Rectangle As Shape
Set Rectangle = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeSnip2DiagRectangle, 582, 144.75, 72, 72)
With Rectangle
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Hello"
End With
```

Or find it later by searching all the shapes (change `Sheet1` to correct sheet)

```
For Each Rectangle In Sheet1.Shapes
    With Rectangle
        If .Type = msoAutoShape Then
            If .AutoShapeType = msoShapeSnip2DiagRectangle Then
                'Do something...
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank your all your helps. I post my code here if you want to recheck it and reproduce the error. Actually, I try to show and hide some shape whenever some buttons are clicked. The point here is that those shapes are assigned macros so I need to call them over and over again.

Code1:
Private Sub EditInformation_Click()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheet5.Unprotect

Sheet5.Cells(2, "C").Locked = False
Sheet5.Range("D2:G2").Locked = False
Sheet5.Range("C8:J115").Locked = False

Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 43")).Width = 318.24
Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Snip Diagonal Corner Rectangle 11")).Visible = False
Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Snip Diagonal Corner Rectangle 14")).Visible = True
Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Snip Diagonal Corner Rectangle 15")).Visible = True
Sheet5.Cells(2, "C").Value = ""
Sheet5.Cells(2, "D").Value = ""
Sheet5.Range("C8:J115").Value = ""
Sheet5.Cells(3, "O").Value = "Edit mode"

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Call CommandButton1_Click

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Code 2:
Sub DiscardButon()

```
Sheet5.Unprotect
Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 43")).Width = 166.32
Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Snip Diagonal Corner Rectangle 11")).Visible = True
Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Snip Diagonal Corner Rectangle 14")).Visible = False
Sheet5.Shapes.Range(Array("Snip Diagonal Corner Rectangle 15")).Visible = False
Sheet5.Range("C2:G2").Value = ""
Sheet5.Range("C8:J115").Value = ""
Sheet5.Cells(3, "O").Value = ""
Sheet5.Protect
```

End Sub